# What is wrong with my visual basic script?

Tags: vbscript

This is the code:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")     
WshShell.Run """C:\Users\dashboard\Desktop\CallOverzichtLive.pbix"""     
WScript.Sleep 15000    
WshShell.AppActivate "CallOverzichtLive - Power BI Designer Preview"    
WshShell.SendKeys "{%(1)}"
```

It gives an

> invalid call or argument

error at line 15 char 1.

I don't see what I'm doing wrong, can anyone help me??

Comment: So what's at line 15?

Comment: The WshShell.SendKeys "{%(1)}"

Comment: What key are you trying to send? This is not a correct key you passing there

Comment: i am trying to do alt and 1, but first it needs to send alt and then the 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I think its clear that you are passing the wrong key parameter.

Sends Alt + 1

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.Run """C:\Users\dashboard\Desktop\CallOverzichtLive.pbix"""

WScript.Sleep 15000

WshShell.AppActivate "CallOverzichtLive - Power BI Designer Preview"

WshShell.SendKeys "%{1}"
```

Comment: Thank you very much, not enough reputation to upvote unfortunately but you are my savior ;)